# JSON, AJAX is working on firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I developed a shopping cart using jquery, ajax and json. It is working fine on local server in chrome. But when I run on server using chrome it is not doing anything; but running on firefox.

It is not running first time, but when I came back from another page then it runs.
http://www.scsprojectreports.com/product/coffee-berry-borer.php

**JS CODE**

```
function add_to_cart(cart_qty, cart_itemid) {
    if (cart_qty <= 0 || isNaN(cart_qty)) {
        my_msg('Error', 'Incorrect Quantity');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "shopping_cart.php",
            data: "cart_itemid=" + cart_itemid + "&cart_qty=" + cart_qty,
            success: function (json) {
                $("#shopping_cart").html('');
                var sub_total = 0;
                $.each($.parseJSON(json), function (idx, obj) {
                    // alert(obj.product_name);
                    $("#shopping_cart").append(
                        '<div class="w50">' + obj.qty + ' x </div>' +
                        '<div class="link"><a href="sub-category-detail-view.html">' + obj.product_name + '</a></div>' +
                        '<div style="clear:both"></div>');
                    sub_total += (obj.price * obj.qty);
                    // alert(sub_total);
                });
                $("#sub_total").html('Sub-Total: Rs. ' + sub_total);
                my_msg('Notification', 'Cart Updated Successfully !!');
                $("#msg").html('');
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#msg").html('<img src="loading.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading...">');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<div style="background: #F7F7F7; border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; padding: 10px;">Qty:
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" size="3" value="1">
<a class="button" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="add_to_cart($('#qty').val(),'<?php echo $fetchline['id'];?>')"><span>Buy</span></a>
<span id="msg" style="text-align:center; padding:6px; color:#EB679F; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"></span>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Working fine for me on chrome. What's the issue?

Comment: Its not adding an item in the cart on first time but when I came back from another page then it adds.

Comment: Maybe you just need a `ctrl+f5`. Have you tried on any other PC?

Comment: I tried ctrl+f5 on my PC; still not working. Tried on 4 PC; running on 2 Pcs

Comment: It is working on my windows chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 m

Answer (score 0):

Try Using start Google Chrome with Disable web security. If You are using windows 7 then start Command Prompt as Administrator (Right Click On CMD and Select Run as Administrator) and Paste Following Code

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Here If your chrome installation path is different, then Change path as with your.